# How to create oauth signature in Restlet authorization TBA (signature mathod: HMAC-SHA256)?

Tags: web-services, netsuite, restlet, suitescript2.0, netsuite-rest-api

I am new in NetSuite Integration, after having an endpoint API, i m trying to call it and for authorization i have consumer key, consumer secret, token id and token secret. Can anyone help me in how to get the `oauth_signature` in restlet script?

When i test the provided endpoint in postman, i get that the header automatically set with :

```
OAuth realm              = "123456_SB1", 
oauth_consumer_key       = "asdfghjklzxcvbnmwertyui234567892345678ertyuicvbnxcvbndfgher56", 
oauth_token              = "dfsfsfddafdcvbnmwertyui234567892345678ertyuicvbnxasdasadsdafd", 
oauth_signature_method   = "HMAC-SHA256", 
oauth_timestamp          = "1705502763", 
oauth_nonce              = "3RTZ9gFUmt", 
oauth_version            = "1.0", 
oauth_signature          = "WERUTUIIYO23456709SDFG576F"
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT THEY ARE DUMMY VALUES.

I tried to have this in generated in my restlet but couldnt get a proper breakthough.

Sorry if i have my concepts unclear, this is becaue i m very new in integrations and rest architecture.

Comment: Are you trying to call a RESTlet or make a call to an oauth1 protected endpoint from a RESTlet? For the former there are quite a few answers on this site for that.

Comment: I am trying to call an oauth1 protected endpoint from my RESTlet script.

Comment: If the oauth1 protected endpoint's code is on the same account as the RESTlets code, then just POST back the the relative URL and call the oauth1 protected endpoint's code directly using a require() load or include the protected code as an AMD module